# I am using node.js and working on a collaborative tool for students and i want to use fabric js in my node project but it is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, fabricjs

I am working with [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and want to use [fabricjs](/questions/tagged/fabricjs) in my project but it is not working with my project and I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

// create a rectangle object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 100,
  height: 100
});

// "add" rectangle onto canvas
canvas.add(rect);
```

I am also including the lib files of [fabricjs](/questions/tagged/fabricjs), here I am able to draw a rectangle on canvas but the rectangle cannot be resized, moved or rotated.

This is the issue I am facing here. According to [fabricjs](/questions/tagged/fabricjs) we can do so by only drawing shapes we do not need to include anything else.

Comment: Are you sure you're running it on node? What fabric.js version are you using?

Comment: @shkaper i am using version 2.4.3 fabricjs and nodejs version 10.13.0, and i am sure that i am running it on nodejs it is a kind of collaborative tool with socket.io.